# Restore old Chrome Profile on OSX Mojave?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, passwords, data-recovery, restore

I spent a week sorting through all data on my Google account a couple weeks ago. Today I looked at the password manager, and it's back to what it was before I edited it. I suspect using Chrome on my phone messed it all up... I hate broken synchronization.

So I remembered Google saves "Profile 1", "Profile 2", etc in `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome`, which I assume saves user data from points in time. I also use Time Machine so I have access to all the data that should, in theory, restore my hard work.

How can I restore a specific state of my passwords? I tried duplicating the older Profile folder and renaming it by a bigger number than my current latest profile, but that didn't change anything.